# Что делает эта часть кода?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```
function User(name){
    this.name = name;
}

User.prototype.hello = function(who){
    console.log("Hello, " + who.name); };

var vasya = new User("Вася");  var petya = new User("Петя");

vasya.hello(petya); petya.hello(vasya);
```

У меня вопросы только по одной части кода:
**this.name = name;**

1. Что делает эта часть кода?
2. Зачем ключевое слово this? Что оно делает?
3. Я так понимаю "name" слева от равно это параметр функции, а справа тогда что?

P.S.Прошу ссылки не бросать на книги или сайты по this, я читал но не понял, хочу разобраться а не просто заучить определение.

Comment: `this.name = name` может быть и `this.someVar = name` в этом случае. Если мы дальше из функции создаём объект, то  в этом случае `this` будет являться так называемым контекстом вызова. Говоря `this`, мы говорим, что вот по этому адресу в памяти есть некий объект, который имеет переменную name в нашем случае, и именно с переменной name, относящейся к вот этому конкретному (`this`) объекту по конкретно этому (`this`) адресу в памяти мы будем сейчас взаимодействовать. Тут трудно понять с первого раза. Поработаешь чуть и поймёшь сам. Или просто в разных источниках смотри. `this` - ЭТОТ объект.

Comment: _Я так понимаю "name" слева от равно это параметр функции_ - нет, параметр функции - справа. слева - поле `this`

Comment: Если считать что у нас:this.someVar = name то перефразировав твои слова:
Если мы дальше из функции создаём объект, то в этом случае this будет являться так называемым контекстом вызова. Говоря this, мы говорим, что вот по этому адресу в памяти есть некий объект, который имеет переменную someVar в нашем случае, и именно с переменной someVar, относящейся к вот этому конкретному (this) объекту по конкретно этому (this) адресу в памяти мы будем сейчас взаимодействовать.
Правильно понял?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this в функции при вызове с new работает как в конструкторе, то есть

```js
function User(name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

эквивалентно

```js
class User{
   constructor(name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
}
```

1. В `this.name = name` мы присваиваем новому объекту как name параметр name.
2. `this` - ключевое слово, по которому мы обращаемся к объекту из его метода или конструктора
3. Справа у нас поле `name` от нового объекта

Comment: "мы присваиваем новому объекту как name параметр name". `this.name` - это не объект.

Comment: "Справи у нас поле name от нового объекта"
Тоесть name справа переменная или что?

Answer (score 1):

> У меня вопросы только по одной части кода: this.name = name;

В данном случае значение переменной `name` присваивается свойству `name` объекта `this`.